# Removing duplicate letters-Word correction

Tags: c++

I have written code that will check the first two letters if they are same, it will remove one and correct the word. but it's not working what's the issue?

```
char word[4];
int i;
 cout<<"Enter Word:";
 for(i=0;i<5;i++) cin>>word[i]; 


for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
if(word[i]==word[i+1]){
for(int k=y;k<5;k++){
    word[i]=word[i+1];
}   
    for(int g=0;g<5;g++)
cout<<word[i];
}
```

}

Comment: for(int y=0;y< **5** ;y++) - you need to change the 5 to 4. and also in the next loop!

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
if(word[i]==word[i+1]){
```

Needs to be:

```
if(word[y]==word[y+1]){
```

In fact, nearly all references to  `i` need to be to the appropriate loop variable.

In addition, most of the literal `5`s need to be `4`s instead.  (You want to iterate through the values 0, 1, 2, and 3.  You do not want to access `word[4]` (it doesn't exist).

Finally, the line:

```
for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
```

should be:

```
for(int y=0;y<3;y++){
```

because you are going to access `word[y+1]`

Comment: Thanks Buddy :) moreover if I set the array size to be 15 than what will be loops indexing?

Comment: Nearly all the indexes should be `sizeof(word)`.  One should be `sizeof(word)-1`.  If you write it like that, you can change the count to your heart's content.

Comment: Okay, last one Pls, I want the user to enter any length of string, how can I set that?

Comment: Don't use a fixed size array. Use a std::string. You can read that in a single go (no need for a loop), and then all the loops need to be to ` word.length()` (or that -1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop till the end of the array. you need to go till the place before the last one.

And also you need to change the **i** in the index to the loops.

```
  char word[4];
    int i;
     cout<<"Enter Word:";
     for(i=0;i<5;i++) 
       cin>>word[i];



for(int y=0;y<4;y++){
if(word[y]==word[y+1]){
for(int k=y;k<4;k++){
    word[k]=word[k+1];
}   
for(int g=0;g<5;g++)
  cout<<word[g];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks  :) moreover if I set the array size to be 15 than what will be loops indexing?

Comment: @Smärtßõý then you will change the 5 to 12 and the 4 to 13. if it was a good answer please mark it as an answer and vote up